# Defining a foreign key based on "dynamic" schema name

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I know that [Postgres allows you to define foreign keys across schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095268/foreign-key-reference-to-table-in-another-schema).

I take advantage of this in my multi-tenant application where each tenant is given their own schema. In addition to their own tables, tenants also "own" some records inside the public schema, so I can do:

```
ALTER TABLE tenant_schema.some_table ADD (
  CONSTRAINT workspace_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (workspace_id)
    REFERENCES public.workspaces(id)
)
```

The `public.workspaces` table looks like this:

```
|--------------------|    |---------------------------|
|  public.workspaces |    | tenant_1642.organizations |
|--------------------|    |---------------------------|
|         id         |    |          id               |
|        name        |    |       workspace_id        |
|     schema_name    |    |        org_name           |
|      subdomain     |    |         address           |
|--------------------|    |---------------------------|
```

I use this design to route web requests to the appropriate schema based on the subdomain. For example, if someone makes a request to `https://org1.fancyapp.com/resource/id`, I can do a lookup on `org1` under "public.workspaces", then know to route that request to "schema_org1.sessions" to see if their session cookie is valid.

This seems to work fine, insofar as it works fine in my dev and test environments, and my test cases are passing, etc. But I'm still fiddling with the design.

My questions:

1. If the tenant_schema is dropped using DROP SCHEMA -schema- CASCADE (which is what I do when someone cancels their subscription and deletes their account), will Postgres know to automatically delete the associated record under public.workspaces?
2. How do I tie the workspace back to the record under tenant_schema.organizations? In other words, how can I add a foreign key (e.g. `organization_id`) to public.workspaces such that the relationship is defined *dynamically* based on the value under the `schema_name` column?

Is there a way to dynamically interpolate the value of a column when defining the foreign key relationship? e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE public.workspaces ADD (
  CONSTRAINT organization_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (organization_id)
    REFERENCES ${public.workspaces.schema_name_col_value}.organizations(id)
)
```

3. Is there some other way do handle this type of requirement (i.e. allow a given email address to register multiple accounts, each with its own subdomain under a unique constraint, e.g. Slack) with regards to database design?

Comment: Is it required, that the schemas are different between tenants, i.e. does the structure look different for different tenants?

Comment: Each schema has the same table structure. Previously I was using table-based multi-tenancy model, but I switched to schema-based. https://vladmihalcea.com/database-multitenancy/

Comment: But it seems to me the table based model would better suit your needs asked here.

Comment: I switched to the schema-based model because it makes it way easier to enforce record ownership (e.g. so that I don't have to make sure the row's "owner_id" matches the request's requester_id before every single query), and overall it seems to be the "recommended" approach for multi-tenancy in Postgres.

Comment: Well, with the different schemas, I'd guess you need (constraint) triggers (or maybe rules) to do what you've asked for.